# Calculating mouse velocity with accuracy

Tags: javascript

I made a little script intended to output the speed at which the mouse moves. The issues I am having is that occasionally the script will output an inaccurate number among the numbers and throw the whole thing off. As well, the script does not always terminate when the user releases the mouse button. To solve the first issue I assume I could probably place the values into an array and then determine the outlier, but I'm hoping somebody here can just tell me I'm doing something stupid and there is a way to fix my code to make it more efficient.

JS:

```
var test_obj = {
    mouse_coors: function(x2) {

        $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
            var x = e.clientX,
            velocity = Math.abs(x-x2);

            console.log(velocity);
            $(document).off("mousemove");

            setTimeout(function() {
                x2 = e.clientX;
                test_obj.mouse_coors(x2);
            }, 100);
        });

        $(document).on("mouseup", function() {
            $(document).off("mouseup").off("mousemove");
        });
    },
};


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#testbox').on("mousedown", function() {
        test_obj.mouse_coors(0);
    });

});
```

HTML:

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mkb2t/

Answer (score 14):

Simply because that is not the velocity of the mouse. What you currently are counting is how far the mouse moved in x-direction. That's called *distance*.

The inaccuracy you experience might both stem from ignoring the y-direction and the inaccuracy of `setTimeout` - use `Date` timestamps.

Also, you are building a cascade of `mousemove` handlers (which not only is incorrect but bad efficiency-wise). On every event (and they're quite often!) you are waiting 0.1s and then add a new listener that will output on every event from then how far the mouse moved since the first event. Another issue is that you're calling the `mouse_coors` function with a value of `0` when the mouse is pressed, yet the mouse hardly will be there.

Better: Store the current coordinates of the mouse globally. Every time when you will update them, compute the difference and divide that by the time that passed since last update. Then log the velocity.

```
function makeVelocityCalculator(e_init, callback) {
    var x = e_init.clientX,
        y = e_init.clientY,
        t = Date.now();
    return function(e) {
        var new_x = e.clientX,
            new_y = e.clientY,
            new_t = Date.now();
        var x_dist = new_x - x,
            y_dist = new_y - y,
            interval = new_t - t;
        var velocity = Math.sqrt(x_dist*x_dist+y_dist*y_dist)/interval;
        callback(velocity);
        // update values:
        x = new_x;
        y = new_y;
        t = new_t;
    };
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testbox').on("mousedown", function(e) {
        var log = makeVelocityCalculator(e, function(v) {
            console.log(v+"pixel/ms");
        });
        $(document).on("mousemove", log).one("mouseup", function(){
            $(document).off("mousemove", log);
        });
    });
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkb2t/2/)

Comment: I'm not trying to get the y direction. Maybe velocity was a misnomer because I don't care about the direction, just the horizontal distance travelled over time. Thanks!

Comment: @tomc: OK, but still you forgot the time… I think my script is easy to adapt for getting horizontal velocity only.

Comment: I assumed that the timeout would account for the time since it creates a pause between gathering the coordinates, but yours does seem more accurate!

Comment: `setTimeout` is not meant to be accurate

Comment: @tomc: But it didn't pause to gather new coordinates, but pause before setting up a new listener. That might've worked with `.one("mousemove", …)`, but not like your script. Still it then wouldn't account for the time between setting up the listener and getting that first event. [Here is something similiar](http://jsfiddle.net/mkb2t/4/) with `setTimeout` for comparison

Comment: JavaScript engine is one-threaded. `setTimeout` and `setInterval` aren't fired at the exact time you'd expect them to be and that leads to inaccurate calculations. Mind that.